# Kissfft from ADC, Microcontroller with C( Buffer problem)

Tags: c, fft, microcontroller, avr, adc

Hello im having a bit of trubble with getting KissFFT to work on my ATmega32a. I am pretty sure it's a problem with how im handling my buffers, but im not completly sure tbh :S

Edit:
Sorry im new here :S

But the problem is, my code is running fine by loading data from my adc, putting into the buffer and then print to UART. But then when i try to implement the kissfft buffer format "kiss_fft_cpx", Then i cant even print the cx_in buffer to UART or anything for that matter. So im pretty sure it must be somwehere around the buffers I have messed it up. The code is building without any wanings , errors or anything.

```
int main()
{
    char str[50];
    UART_init();
    ADC_Init();
    int ADC_VALUE;
    int i = 0;
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_in[BUFFER_SIZE];
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_out[BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    kiss_fft_cfg cfg = kiss_fft_alloc( i ,0 ,0,0 );
    while(1)
    {
        kiss_fft_cfg cfg;
        
        if (i == BUFFER_SIZE - 1){
            kiss_fft( cfg , cx_in , cx_out );
            sprintf(str,"X =%d\t",cx_in[0]);
            UART_SendString(str);
            free(cfg);
            i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < BUFFER_SIZE)
                ADC_VALUE = ADC_Read(0);
            cx_in[i].r = ADC_VALUE;
            cx_in[i].i = 0;
            i++;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try your code?

Comment: “I’m having trouble” is not an actionable statement. Please [edit] your post to clearly state what the trouble is. See [ask].

Comment: One obvious issue is that `cfg`, which points to something allocated, is shadowed inside the loop by another variable with the same name, which is never assigned anything.

Comment: “i cant even print …” but what happens? Does your program crash? Does it loop indefinitely? Does it not start up? Does it run fine but produce no output?

Comment: Did you turn on all warnings in your compiler? For example in GCC you should add `-Wall` to get most useful diagnostics.

Comment: when `i == BUFFER_SIZE - 1` the `else` branch is not executed, therefore, the last item in the array is never filled.

Comment: I apologize for the bit late answer, but thanks for the coments.
I tried to edit my question to be more precise. 
But nothing happens when I run the code, after adding the "kiss_fft_cpx" class instad of int. and add the kissfft lines.
I'm not sure what you mean with the cfg, but if you can explain or show i would appriciate :D.
@Cris

Comment: Can you elaborate with the `i == BUFFER_SIZE - 1`, because it seems to be running fine, without the kissfft part. and Im doing a `i = 0;` to reset.

Comment: Before the loop you call `kiss_fft_alloc` and assign the result to variable `cfg`. Then inside the loop you create a new variable `cfg` which shadows the one outside the loop, and is not initialized. This is a pointer to a random location in memory, if you try to dereference this pointer (which happens eventually when you call `kiss_fft` with that pointer as argument), your program will most likely crash, at best it will do an FFT with random configuration. (1/2)

Comment: I'm sure there are other issues in the code, the whole thing looks very weird, including the infinite loop without a `break` inside, and the `free` call in the middle of the loop, freeing a resource you'll likely be using again in a later loop iteration. (2/2)

Comment: Thanks again for the fast answer, I realy appriciate it. I will try and look into the cfg.